# check all check boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m having some problems with some JavaScript I created. When a item from check all is Unchecked it needs to remove the checked from the checked all box, also when the check all is checked I don’t want to to pull through the other items only the check all box.

```
check all, item 1, item 2
```

Remove item 1 and check all un-checks and all that gets pulled through is item. If check all is checked the item 1 and item 2 are checked but then not pulled through.

```js
// all "check all" checkboxes will have the class "checkall"
// and the id to match the location, e.g. wales, etc

$(".checkall").on('change', function() {

  // all normal checkboxes will have a class "chk_xxxxxx"
  // where "xxxx" is the name of the location, e.g. "chk_wales"

  // get the class name from the id of the "check all" box
  var checkboxesClass = '.chk_' + $(this).attr("id");

  // now get all boxes to check
  var boxesToCheck = $(checkboxesClass);

  // check all the boxes
  boxesToCheck.prop('checked', this.checked);
});


// display what the user has chosen
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {

  $("#checked").empty();

  $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {

    // see if it is a "check all" box
    if ($(this).attr("class") === "checkall") {
      // Display the id of the "check all" box
      $("#checked").html($("#checked").html() + '<h3>' + $(this).attr("id").toUpperCase() + "</h3>");
    } else {
      // display the label text for all normal checkboxes
      $("#checked").html($("#checked").html() + $(this).next().text() + "<br>");
    }

  });
});


// With some more work you could make the Check All headings show when only one or two checkboxes were checked. It depends how you need it to work.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <input type="checkbox" id="wales" class="checkall" value="1">
  <label for="wales">Check All</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem1" value="2" class="chk_wales">
  <label for="checkItem1">Item 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem2" value="2" class="chk_wales">
  <label for="checkItem2">Item 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem3" value="2" class="chk_wales">
  <label for="checkItem3">Item 3</label>

  <hr />

  <input type="checkbox" id="west" class="checkall" value="3">
  <label for="west">Check All</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem4" value="4" class="chk_west">
  <label for="checkItem4">Item 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem5" value="4" class="chk_west">
  <label for="checkItem5">Item 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem6" value="4" class="chk_west">
  <label for="checkItem6">Item 3</label>

  <hr />

  <input type="checkbox" id="east" class="checkall" value="5">
  <label for="east">Check All</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem7" value="6" class="chk_east">
  <label for="checkItem7">Item 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem8" value="6" class="chk_east">
  <label for="checkItem8">Item 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem9" value="6" class="chk_east">
  <label for="checkItem9">Item 3</label>

  <p>You have selected:</p>

  <div id="checked">


  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please explain clearly?

Answer (score 0):

This code should work if im not mistaken what you are trying to say. I have done for first set of checkboxes. You can do it for next two:

```js
$("#check1 input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
    if($("#check1 input[type=checkbox]:checked").length == $("#check1 input[type=checkbox]").length) {
       $("#wales").prop("checked",true);
    }
    else {
        $("#wales").prop("checked",false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="wales" class="checkall" value="1">
<label for="wales">Check All</label>
<section id="check1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem1" value="2" class="chk_wales">
    <label for="checkItem1">Item 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem2" value="2" class="chk_wales">
    <label for="checkItem2">Item 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem3" value="2" class="chk_wales">
    <label for="checkItem3">Item 3</label>
</section>
```

**UPDATE**

This will fulfill your requirement. Remove your **$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function()** code and use the updated one

```js
$("#check1 input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function()
    {
        $("#checked").empty();
        if($("#check1 input[type=checkbox]:checked").length == $("#check1 input[type=checkbox]").length)
        {

            $("#wales").prop("checked", true);

            // Display the id of the "check all" box
            $("#checked").html($("#checked").html() + "<h3>Wales</h3>");

        }
        else
        {
            $("#wales").prop("checked", false);
            $("#check1 input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function()
            {
                $("#checked").html($("#checked").html() + $(this).next().text() + "<br>");
            });
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="wales" class="checkall" value="1">
<label for="wales">Check All</label>
<section id="check1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem1" value="2" class="chk_wales">
    <label for="checkItem1">Item 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem2" value="2" class="chk_wales">
    <label for="checkItem2">Item 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem3" value="2" class="chk_wales">
    <label for="checkItem3">Item 3</label>
</section>
<hr/>
<div id="checked">


</div>
```

**Another Update**

```js
$(".checkall").on('change', function()
    {

        // all normal checkboxes will have a class "chk_xxxxxx"
        // where "xxxx" is the name of the location, e.g. "chk_wales"

        // get the class name from the id of the "check all" box
        var checkboxesClass = '.chk_' + $(this).attr("id");

        // now get all boxes to check
        var boxesToCheck = $(checkboxesClass);

        // check all the boxes
        boxesToCheck.prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

$("#check1 input[type=checkbox], #wales").on("change", function()
    {
        checkBoxes();
    });

    function checkBoxes()
    {

        $("#checked").empty();
        if($("#check1 input[type=checkbox]:checked").length == $("#check1 input[type=checkbox]").length)
        {

            $("#wales").prop("checked", true);

            // Display the id of the "check all" box
            $("#checked").html($("#checked").html() + "<h3>Wales</h3>");

        }
        else
        {
            $("#wales").prop("checked", false);
            $("#check1 input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function()
            {
                $("#checked").html($("#checked").html() + $(this).next().text() + "<br>");
            });
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="wales" class="checkall" value="1">
<label for="wales">Check All</label>
<section id="check1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem1" value="2" class="chk_wales">
    <label for="checkItem1">Item 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem2" value="2" class="chk_wales">
    <label for="checkItem2">Item 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem3" value="2" class="chk_wales">
    <label for="checkItem3">Item 3</label>
</section>
<hr/>
<div id="checked">


</div>
```

Comment: ok it does work but only when you remove 2 items if you remove item 3 first wales doent remove

Comment: ah so close, when you remove a item when they are all check it doesnt remove the checked all.. http://jsbin.com/xiqemiqadu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: nope now it seams to show all the items now when checked, however works the otherway again

Comment: yes this works :-), how would you do this with multi able items?

Comment: You have to make the function dynamic. Pass id as parameter

Comment: any chance you could update the code im not quite sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'pulled through', but unchecking the check-all can be achieved through:

```
if (!$currentCheckbox.hasClass('checkall')) {    
    var $previousCheckAll = $currentCheckbox.prevAll('.checkall');        
    if ($previousCheckAll.length>0)
    {
        $previousCheckAll.first().prop('checked',false);    
    }        
}
```

Just insert the code above beneath the line

```
 $("#checked").empty();
```

of your JSbin.